# Global Variable Does not hold in PHP

Tags: php

I have a page, header.php that, among many things, offers the user of my site a place to sign in. It loads, settings, database functions and a CSS file. In the settings file I declare a global variable $username. In header.php I have the following code:

```
if(!isset($username)){
  echo'<div class = "loginSpace">';
  echo'
  <form action = "checkLogin.php" method = "post">
  Username: <input type = "text" name = "username" size = 14/>
  <br>Password: <input type = "password" name = "pass" size = 14 />
  <input type = "submit" value = "Sign In"/>
  </form>
  </div>';
}
else{
     $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$db_prefix}Users WHERE Username = '{$username}'");
     $userInfo = mysql_fetch_array($result);
     echo '<div class = "loginSpace">
     Welcome ' . $userInfo['FirstName'] .'
     <form action = "index.php" method = "post"> '; 
     $username = "";
     echo'<input type = "submit" value = "Log out"/>
     </form>
     </div>';
     }
```

In checklogin, I have:

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['pass'];
require_once('Header.php');
```

The username is held and the proper "heading" shows up when you get redirected to checkLogin.php, however, if you click a link to go to another page of the site, the username is forgotten.

Am I forgetting something? Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

i dont understand your question clearly but 
have you declared username as a global variable in header.php?? if so, in every page if you are including header.php, you first write,

```
global $header;
```

and then use the variable $header.

web pages are stateless, so to maintain state you can either use cookie or sessions or hidden fields.

Answer (score 1):

in another link the username will be forgot since you are using the `post` if you want to access user name on ever page user `SESSION` instead

you should  check first

```
if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['pass']))  {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
   $password = $_POST['pass'];

}
```

and

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$db_prefix}Users WHERE Username = '{$username}'");
                                                 ^---there should be space
```

Comment: Well... yes. But that still doesn't solve the fact that "username", a global variable, isn't being held farther than that page...

Comment: @longlost10 the POST variable will pass to only action page ... to pass the usrname on ever page you can either user the session or get method i would recommend you to use the session

Comment: I changed the if statement in header.php to `if(!isset($_SESSION['username']))` and in checkLogin to `$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];` but it's still not holding...

Comment: @longlost10 i think `$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];` should be `$_SESSION['username'] == $_POST['username'];`